# How can I find out if New York State's Department of Education accredits more than just high schools, and if there is a list of their institutions?

Tags: accreditation

I'm looking into schools that are accredited. I saw that NY state department of education gives accreditation to institutions, but I simply cannot tell if this is only for high schools. Also, I can't find a list of the high schools they accredit.

How can I find this information?

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that the states accredit secondary education. They don't accredit colleges and universities, but have some say in policies.

Accreditation in the US is handled by private agencies that are, themselves, accredited to the US department of education. Most of these are regional and accredit most of the colleges and universities within their region. There are a few specialized agencies as well, but they, too, require accreditation from the US department of education.

On the other hand, the states can permit universities to offer certain degrees. So, a university, to offer a doctoral degree in a given field, needs something like a license from the state. But we have fifty states and so I can't guarantee that this is a uniform practice.

Most universities will have a web presence that makes their accreditation prominent. They will probably name the main accrediting agency and link to it.

See: https://www.chea.org/regional-accrediting-organizations-accreditor-type

And one university has the following information: https://accreditation.umich.edu/history/

And some fields have separate accreditation for programs.

Comment: States really only have say over majors/degrees at state-funded schools, and that is mostly to concentrate funding to support one viable program vs multiple sub-par programs.

Comment: @JonCuster, actually that isn't true. New York has control over doctoral programs even at private universities. You need state permission to offer a PhD in field X. I have direct evidence of this. The university was accredited and allowed to offer PhDs in some areas, but new programs needed vetting. But other states have their own rules on such things.

Comment: I'm having a hard time believing that New York would tell Columbia "no" - they have no real leverage and would quickly lose any PR battle over it. The SUNY system, CUNY, and the state-supported portions of Cornell they have leverage over.

Comment: @JonCuster Still, it happened. But you have caught part of the reason. Some of it is political. A few schools can apply a lot of pressure on the state agencies.

Comment: it also turns out that universities have leverage over both the state and accreditation bodies, so it cuts both ways. One state told a university it would stop giving teaching credentials to their liberal arts graduates (who did a lot of un-credited work on things like practice teaching) unless they implemented all the 'how to teach' courses in an education degree. The state backed down after every school district who had hired such a student told them they were being stupid.